# Troubleshooting SaveAs button through MS Access Navigation form

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax

i've been struggling around trying to get my VBA to work & i'm at a loss since i'm extremely fresh using VBA or coding in-general.

What i've got is basically a Navigation Main Form that uses tabs to open up different forms for ease of access. On one of these subforms there is a button that is supposed to work as a "SaveAsPDF" option. it's basically supposed to work by opening up a folder you want to save it in, & exporting the Report version as a pdf to the location. The weird thing is that it works perfectly when you have the actual form open & not the form open in the navigation menu, so i'm at a loss now.

If anyone is able to help, it's much appreciated & you'll be saving alot of hair from the floor. What i've got is below

---

```
Private Sub SaveAsPDF_Click()
Dim fd As FileDialog
On Error goto ErrorHandler

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    With fd
        .InitialFileName = MAFNO & ".pdf"

    End With

If fd.Show Then
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "RptMAFPrint", acFormatPDF, _
    fd.SelectedItems(1), True
End If

Exit sub

ErrorHandler:
Msgbox "An Error occurred, please try again", vbinformation, "Could not save document"
Exit sub

End Sub
```

As far as it running on it's own when you open the actual form up, it works perfectly & hasn't had a single error, but when opening it up from the Navigation Menu Tab it immediately has an error & tries to save the entire workbook.
**Error below**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqIEq.jpg

Comment: Error messages should be provided as text in question, not just image which can be hard to read (like in this case). What do you mean by "tries to save the entire workbook" - what workbook? Is FrmMAF the main form? Is this prompt coming from the report? If not the main form and is subform, references to a form will be different when that form is used as a subform. This will cause reference in report to trigger popup input prompt when the form cannot be found.

Comment: Yes, as I said in the question, the database uses a Navigation Form & using the tabs it will open up other forms when you cycle through the tabs. However when you open the FrmMAF by itself the SaveAs button works fine. Currently how i have it setup like above, is when you have FrmMAF open & you then open the Report version, it will open to the same ID number that the record is on. So if you have FrmMAF open on record 1 [ID 1], then open the report version (RptMAF) it will open up to the record of ID 1

Comment: Well, the query behind the form has a form value parameter. When the form is loaded, the query can get its value, but when the form is closed, the query is looking for it via the popup (manual input).

Comment: When i said "saving the workbook", that was my mistake, it was doing that just before i posted here because that was what it would try to do before i changed how the Rpt version works.
But the error is it looking for a parameter field of [ID] like below with a search box

Forms!FrmMAF!ID 
Please enter a value = ___


is there a different way i need to make the Report work when being opened from the Navigation form or something? because it works fine if you just open up FrmMAF & hit SaveAs. It runs through everything just fine & has no issues, but not from the Navigation Form

Comment: Open the form in hidden mode and close it when the export is complete. Or find another way to pass the parameter to the query.

Comment: Hidden Mode? That's definitely new to me. Can you explain a little bit or is it something super simple?

Comment: See the `WindowMode` argument of the `DoCmd.OpenForm` method. Set it to `acHidden`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.openform

Comment: That'll do it, thank you, i really appreciate it. She works like a charm now

Comment: Don't forget to close the hidden form instances as access will crash eventually. Also, cancelling an export throws an error, so make sure to handle it and close the hidden form there. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longpast on this post, but Kostas had the answer & I was easily able to edit the vba to make it work. Thank you thank you kostas, if I could actually put yours as the answer, I would.

VBA is below if anyone would ever need it. I'll probably go back at some point & see if I could re-write it better, but it gets the job done for the most part.
This does work perfectly for a MS Access Navigation form though & it does not close the current active tab at the end of the VBA.

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveAsPDF_Click()
Dim fd As FileDialog
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

DoCmd.Save
DoCmd.RefreshRecord

'====  Initial Check  ====

If IsNull(Me.TxtMAFNumberTop) Then
    GoTo Leave

ElseIf Not IsNull(Me.TxtMAFNumberTop) Then
    GoTo Start

End If

'====  SaveAs PDF Start  ====
Start:
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        With fd
        .InitialFileName = TxtMAFNumberTop & ".pdf"
    
        End With

    If fd.Show Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "FrmMAF", acNormal, , "[ID] = " & ID, , acHidden
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "RptMAFPrint", acFormatPDF, _
        fd.SelectedItems(1), True
        DoCmd.Close , "FrmMAF"

    End If

Exit Sub

Leave:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred trying to print your MAF. Please try the following 
below & try again" & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "1) Verify current MAF information & fields are correct" & vbCrLf & _
    "2) Cycle Records & try again " & vbCrLf & _
    vbCrLf & _
    "If this problem occurs again please contact your local Administrator", _
    vbCritical + vbRetryCancel, _
    "[Critical] ERROR : SaveAsPDF "

    If vbRetry Then
        GoTo Start
    
    ElseIf vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    
    End If

End Sub
```